# Weierstrass normal form

Tags: elliptic-curves

How can I show that the Weierstrass  normal form  $u^3 + v^3 = \alpha$,with
$x=12\alpha/(u+v)$    and           $y=36\alpha (u-v)/(u+v)$,
 satisfy      $y^2=x^3-432α^2$
?

Answer (score 1):

Since $u^3 + v^3 = (u+v)(u^2 - uv + v^2)$, we can clear the fractions in the expressions for $x$ and $y$ by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $(u^2 - uv + v^2)$: $$ x = 12 (u^2 - uv + v^2)$$ $$ y= 36(u-v)(u^2 - uv + v^2)$$  Then substitute these expressions for $x, y, \alpha$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ into $y^2 = x^3 - 432\alpha^2$.  [Simplify](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20%2812%28u%5E2%20-%20u%20v%20%2b%20v%5E2%29%29%5E3%20-%20432%20%28u%5E3%2bv%5E3%29%5E2%20-%20%2836%20%28u-v%29%20%28u%5E2%20-%20u%20v%20%2b%20v%5E2%29%29%5E2), and everything cancels out, as desired.

This proof is not particularly enlightening, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this is an ooold question here. Note that the given substitution is birational from the $(u,v)$-world to the $(x,y)$-world, in formulas:
$$
\begin{aligned} 
x &= 12a\cdot\frac 1{u+v}\ , &  y &= 36a\cdot \frac{u-v}{u+v}\ ,\\
u &= \frac 1{6x}(36a-y)\ ,   &  v &= \frac 1{6x}(36a+y)\ .
\end{aligned} 
$$
I am writing $a$ instead of $\alpha$.
The above substitutions are functions $f:(u,v)\to (x,y)$ given by the first line, and $g:(x,y)\to(u,v)$ given by the second line. It is easy to see that in a generic point $(u,v)$ resp. $(x,y)$ we have $gf(u,v)=(u,v)$, resp. $fg(x,y)=(x,y)$. For instance:
$$
\begin{aligned}
fg(x,y) &=f\left(\frac 1{6x}(36a-y)\ ,  \ \frac 1{6x}(36a+y)\right)
\\
&=\left(\ 
12a\cdot 
\frac 1{\frac 1{6x}(36a-y)+ \frac 1{6x}(36a+y)}
\ ,\
36a\cdot 
\frac
{\frac 1{6x}(36a-y)- \frac 1{6x}(36a+y)}
{\frac 1{6x}(36a-y)+ \frac 1{6x}(36a+y)}\ 
\right)
\\
&=(x,y)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Let us show that using these substitutions the two equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
&u^3 + v^3 = a\ ,\\
&y^2 = x^3 - 432a^2\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
are mapped in each other. Assume $u^3+v^3=a$. Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x^3 - y^2 &= 
432a^2\frac{4a}{(u+v)^2} - 
432a^2\frac{3(u-v)^2}{(u+v)^2} 
\\
&= 432a^2\cdot \frac{4a\ - \ (3u^3-3u^2v-3uv^3+3v^3)}{u^3+3u^2v+3uv^3+v^3} 
\\
&= 432a^2\cdot \frac{4a\ - \ (3a-3u^2v-3uv^3)}{a+3u^2v+3uv^3} 
\\
&= 432a^2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Conversely, assume $y^2 = x^3 - 432a^2$. Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
u^3 + v^2
&= \frac 1{(6x)^3}\Big(\ (36a-y)^3 + (36a+y)^3\ \Big)
\\
&= \frac 2{(6x)^3}\Big(\ (36a)^3 + 3\cdot(36a)\;y^2\ \Big)
\\
&= \frac {2\cdot3\cdot(36a)}{(6x)^3}\Big(\ 432a^2 + y^2\ \Big)
\\
&= \frac {2\cdot3\cdot(36a)}{(6x)^3}\cdot x^3
\\
&=a\ .
\end{aligned}
$$